# Unable to install Anaconda properly

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I was trying to install Anaconda
I have agreed the license agreement and gave the path C:\Users\USER\anaconda3 for Installation and checked the following option.
[image]

I took 20-30 Mins of time for extracting and installing a number of packages and finally it thrown an error.

Can someone explain what is causing the error?

```
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(52): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: C:\Users\USER\anaconda3
  registry file: C:\Users\USER\.conda\environments.txt
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: ...working... done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script out


put <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

return code: 1

()

Delete file: C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\pkgs\env.txt
Output folder: C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\conda-meta
Extract: history
Creating Anaconda3 menus...
Execute: "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkdirs
Running post install...
Execute: "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" post_install
Execute: "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\pkgs\.cio-config.py" "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64.exe"
Created uninstaller: C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe
Completed
```

kindly give your suggestions what needs to be changed?

Comment: Did you get this just by launching the installer?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I suggest you mark the `Add anaconda3 to my PATH environment variable`. When do you exactly get the error? When you start anaconda? Or try to execute some code?

Answer (score 1):

`Path not writable or missing`: Try to execute the anaconda installer again running it as an administrator.